# StackOverflowException when disposing an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow, dispose

I have created a class to store search values to a session. Such that when I get back to the search page from another page, I can get the values stored in the session. When the search page loads, I'm getting the values from the session, fill up the text fields and dispose the object afterwards. But I get a `StackOverflowException` when I try to dispose the object. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

```
    public class SearchValue : IDisposable{
          public int ID {get; set;}
          public string Name {get; set;}

          public void Dispose()
          {
              this.Dispose();
          }
     }

            public void SaveSearchValueToSession()
            {
                SearchValue searchValue = new SearchValue();
                searchValue.ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
                searchValue.Name = txtName.Text;
                Session["SEARCH_VALUE"] = searchValue;
            }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
      SearchValue searchValue = (SearchValue)Session["SEARCH_VALUE"];
      txtID.Text = searchValue.ID.ToString();
      txtName.Text = searchValue.Name;

      //Right here I would like to dispose the object
      searchValue.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: In Dispose() you always recursively call Dispose()

Comment: What do you expect your Dispose() method to do?

Comment: Why is that class disposable anyway? Seems illogical.

Comment: You don't need to dispose that object. It will be garbage collected (eventually) and there are no unmanaged resources to clean up.  Use disposal only when you have very large objects and want to free memory more quickly or you have unmanaged resources - file handles, sockets, etc. - that need to be cleaned up manually.

Comment: I think I get it now, I'm calling it recursively. Well I'm actually creating a SearchValue object everytime I press the search button. I'm thinking that I'll end up creating too many objects that's why I want to dispose. Can you tell me why this is a bad idea?

Comment: You are storing it into the session, so it is never garbage collected! (until the session is destroyed of course)

Comment: But on my Page_Load function, I'm assigning the object stored in the session to my searchValue object. doesn't it point to the object I created when I press the search button?

Comment: @jmc Dispose is just a method, calling it won't free memory

Comment: @jmc:You are assigning a reference to the object in memory. The object  itself never gets garbage collected.

Comment: Sessions will time out anyways, freeing up the memory. It will garbage collect eventually. That is another thing I don't like about online programming is the sessions... these things are dangerous and you should be using a `QueryString`

Comment: I think query strings instead of sessions would be a good idea. Aside from storing the search results, I could also save the search page I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the same method from inside the `Dispose` method. This will indeed cause a `StackOverflowException`. I do wonder if you really need to implement `IDisposable` and if you understand its purpose...

If you really need to:

1. Give a [meaningful implementation of `Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), free unmanaged resources, etc;
2. Use `using` around the variable;
3. Don't save it inside the `Session` after disposal.

Also read the [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From comments I notice you are worried of creating too much objects. Don't worry, it is no problem here. This is especially true since your object (single) doesn't get garbage collected now: you save it in the session where it will live until the session is distroyed. You keep reusing the very same object over and over again.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm worried about creating too many objects. But based on your answer I think I'll leave it to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem stems from the improper way to implement the `IDisposable` pattern. Here is a short but complete example for implementing it:

```
public class ThisIsDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public ThisIsDisposable() { }

    private bool _isDisposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (!_isDisposed)
            {
                //Do your unmanaged disposing here
                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the class is `sealed`, then the second `Dispose(bool)` method should be marked `private` and not virtual. The primary use of `IDisposable` is to dispose of unmanaged resources. If you don't have unmanaged resources, you can still implement it so that the object can be used in `using` statements, but generally the `Dispose(bool)` overload will not do anything in that case.

See CA1063 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx) and `IDisposable` Interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

As your comments have said, using `IDisposable` will not automatically free memory. Your object will be garbage collected when there are no more references to the object. Storing references to your values and never removing those references will result in a memory leak, so if you want to make sure that you don't leak memory, then you need to make sure that there are no more active references to the objects you create (clear the list/session object,etc).

In your case, it is completely unnecessary to implement this pattern because your objects are not used in `using` statements and they don not consume managed resources.

Comment: Thank you. I was into thinking that calling the Dispose() method would automatically dispose off objects. Well, now I've realized that this is just a method of the interface that I need to provide implementation to.

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions is a hard battle. Personally, I only EVER use them for account login status. A query string would help you out here. See the example below.

Page Before

```
Response.Redirect("http://yoursite.com/search?id=12");
```

Then on the search page (assuming) (Page Load)

```
// usual if(!Page.PostBack)

int searchId = -1;
if(Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
   String searchIdStr = Request.QueryString["id"]
   if(searchIdStr != String.Empty)
   {
       try{ 
          searchId = Convert.ToInt32(searchIdStr); 
          SearchValue searchValue = searchValueRepo.GetSearchValues()
            .Find(o => o.ID == searchId);
          if(searchValue == null){
             //Failed to find your search values
          }
       } catch (Exception ex) { //failed to convert to integer };

   }
}
```

Then, if you feel that the user has too much control over the query string you can then set `id=239847hcjdhnsjk` or a salted hash so no one can attempt to change the value to change the behavior of the site.